# How to import date column from csv in python in format d/m/y

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a data sheet in which issue_d is a date column having values stored in a format - 11-Dec. On clicking any cell of the column, date is coming as 12/11/2018.

But  while reading the csv file, issue_d is getting imported as 11-Dec. Year is not getting imported.

How do I get the issue_d column in format- d/m/y?

Code i tried -

```
import pandas
data=pandas.read_csv('Project_data.csv')
print(data)
```

checking issue_d column: data['issue_d']
result :

```
0         11-Dec
1         11-Dec
2         11-Dec
```

expected:

```
0         11-Dec-2018
1         11-Dec-2018
2         11-Dec-201
```

Comment: You need to change the format in the CSV. The values saved are literally the string `'11-Dec'`, so pandas has no way to guess the year should be 2018. If you're working in Excel just right click the column, format cells, Date and then chose a format that includes the year. Resave the csv and then you'll have the year.

Comment: yes, got it. Formatted in csv first and then imported the data in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with add year to column:

```
df['issue_d'] = pd.to_datetime(df['issue_d'] + '-2018')
print (df)
     issue_d
0 2018-12-11
1 2018-12-11
2 2018-12-11
```

Answer (score 0):

A more 'controllable' way of getting the data is to first get the datetime from the data frame as normal, and then convert it:

```
dt = dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

In this case, you'd put %d in front. strftime is a great technique because it allows the most customization when converting a datetime variable, and I used it in my tutorial [book](https://www.energize.ai/stockprediction/) - if you're a beginner to python algorithms, you should definitely check it out!

After you do this, you can splice out each individual month, day, and year, and then use

```
strftime("%B")
```

to get the string-name of the month (e.g. "February").

Good Luck!